# The mechanics of forwardingTargetForSelector: with Core Data classes

Tags: inheritance, ios7, selector

I'd appreciate your guidance on this.  I have a simple Core Data structure:

```
Datum <———————————————-- Model
=====                    =====
dataComment              lastUpdate
                         name
                         ...
```

That is, Model inherits from Datum.  Generated code:

```
@interface Datum : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * dataComment;
@end
```

and

```
@interface Model : Datum
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastUpdate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
```

I use the following code to retrieve data objects:

```
SEL selectorForData = NSSelectorFromString(lclInst.fieldName);
id lclObjectForData = [self.theObjectToEdit performSelector:selectorForData];
```

where lclInst.fieldName is "name", "lastUpdate", or "dataComment".  "name" and "lastUpdate" resolve correctly, but "dataComment" does not (even though Model inherits from Datum).  To get around this, I tried getting as close to the Model class as I could to resolve the problem.  The code for this comes right after the code sample above:

```
if (!lclObjectForData)
{
    id lclStuff = [(Model*)(self.theObjectToEdit) resolveLostSelector:selectorForData ];
}
```

and this is the code for resolveLostSelector:

```
-(id) resolveLostSelector: (SEL) aSelector
{
    id lclSel = [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
    NSLog(@"resolution of SEL: %@", [[lclSel class] description]);
    return lclSel;
}
```

It fails to resolve anything.

Questions:
(1)  I can't easily put code in the Model class since it is generated by Core Data, so I put it into a Model+ModelExt class.  Said class knows all about "dataComment", it can resolve for it me if I put code directly in the method.  If this is not the correct way to get to Model, what is?

(2)  I don't know how to get to the "parent" part (Datum, in this case) of an object from the "child" part (Model, in this case).  I used "super", but that may not be correct.  Normally, I simply say self.name and self.dataComment without regard to the supposed boundary between them, that boundary seems all-to-real in resolving a selector.

(3)  Should I just bag this approach and put "dataComment" into each of the classes that inherit from Datum?

Again, your guidance is much appreciated.  Also, others would appreciate it if somebody with a reputation attached the tag "forwardingTargetForSelector" to this.

Comment: I may be missing something, but can't you just use `[coredataobject valueForKey:lclInst.fieldName]`?

Comment: And you can easily put stuff in an `NSManagedObject` subclass, either add code to the subclass generated by XCode, or use a category (which actually seems to be what you are doing, given the `Model+ModelExt` syntax)